# Firebase cloud functions gen2 (python) versus flask

Tags: python, firebase, flask, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

Firebase has released functions generation 2 which support python natively. Theses functions are deployed to cloud run, so I am wondering is there any benefit of using flask with cloud run now that gen2 is out? Should I choose flask or gen2 functions for my backend deployment?

Comment: You can incrementally adopt if you want [Using with existing Flask apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd#python-preview)